# SQL Query to show parts list with latest revision change

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying to start using MS Access to store some of our company wide data instead of Excel. Beginning with, I'm migrating our CAD data to an access database. For our parts we have Part Numbers, Part Names, Creation data with every part. We also have a list of revisions of the part which have revision number ('A', 'B', 'C', etc) and revision date, where any part can have any amount of revisions associated with it. I have 2 separate tables of 'CAD Parts' and 'Revisions' which have a common key of 'Part Number' to cross reference. I would like to be able to query the list of parts and see the latest revision of the part alongside other information.

[The CAD Parts Library](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0xI6h.png)

[The Revisions Library](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yA8uA.png)

So far I've tried doing the below. I am fairly certain I have got the coding syntax completely wrong, but hopefully it will give an indicator of where I was trying to get to. Most of it is auto generated except for the WHERE segment, which was typed by me. It tells me that there is a syntax error when saving it.

```
SELECT [CAD Parts].[Part Number], [CAD Parts].Description, [CAD Parts].[Date Created], Revisions.Revision, Revisions.[Revision Date]
FROM [CAD Parts] LEFT JOIN Revisions ON [CAD Parts].[Part Number] = Revisions.[Part Number] 
WHERE Revisions.[Revision Date] = select MAX([Revision Date]) from Revisions as R1 WHERE R1.[Part Number] = [CAD Parts].[Part Number]
ORDER BY [CAD Parts].[Part Number];
```

Comment: Is it possible to have more than one review on the same date?

Comment: It is possible but unlikely. Though it would make more sense to instead look for the highest revision letter, in my example I was looking for the highest date because I thought it would be easiest and later on I could experiment with letters.

Comment: In this case, wouldn't the letters repeat and be limited from A to Z? There would need to be a unique identifier in addition to the date, in this case, the letters, or else the table ID itself. Can it be assumed that the highest ID will always be the last revision? Edit: If the revision date field was a datetime it would be possible, but as it is a date it could bring two values.

Comment: Yes for the highest ID question, which would make more sense...but in 3 years, the highest letter we have reached is H so I'm not too concerned about this. My reason for asking this question relates more to how to integrate both tables into the same query - I'm struggling to adapt examples because this task is too particular for my limited SQL knowledge. And then once I have a working model I can alter it into something more long term.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming:

[image]

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|       CADID        |    Part Number     |    Description     |    Date Created    |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                  1 | PAR0001            | Bed                |          12/9/2019 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                  2 | PAR0002            | Strut              |          4/13/2023 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|     RevisionID     |       CADID        |    Part Number     |      Revision      |       Revision Date       |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                  1 |                  1 | PAR0001            | A                  |                 10/4/2023 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                  2 |                  1 | PAR0001            | B                  |                 11/4/2023 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Despite my initial confidence I messed up too many times delimiting both string variables and variable names with spaces so I used number primary keys.  Here is my query:

[image]

```
'LatestRevisionDate in two ways

LatestRevisionDate1: DLookUp("max([Revision Date])","Revisions","CADID = " & [CADID])

LatestRevisionDate2: (SELECT max([Revision Date]) FROM Revisions as r WHERE r.[Part Number] = [CAD Parts].[Part Number] )
```

The above assumes that the max Revision is guaranteed to be the latest revision.  If that is not the case more work is needed.  I'm still using Access 2016 which quietly fails when subqueries are nested in subqueries, but the double dlookup should be:

```
LatestRevision3: IIf(DLookUp("max([Revision Date])","Revisions","CADID = " & [CADID]),DLookUp("Revision","Revisions","[Revision Date] = #" & DLookUp("max([Revision Date])","Revisions","CADID = " & [CADID]) & "#"),Null)
```